# How do I draw a parallel resistors in series with other resistors?

Tags: formatting, circuitikz

I currently have

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
     \begin{circuitikz}
      \draw (0,0)
      to[V,v=$5V$] (0,4) % The voltage source
      to[R=$3.9$\si{\ohm}] (4,4)
      to[R=$19\si{\ohm}$] (4,0) % The resistor
      to[short] (3,0)
      to[short] (3,.5) 
      to [R=$33$\si{\ohm} (1,.5)
      to [short] (1,.5)
      to[short] (1,0) 
      to [short] (1,-.5)
      to [R=$69$\si{\ohm}] (3,-.5)
      to [short] (3,-0.5)
      to[short] (3,0)
   \end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}
```

I can't figure out how to finish the circuit, any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please note that it is preferred if the provided code can be run as a complete document (so includes `\documentclass`, the necessary `\usepackage`s and `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`), while still being as minimal as possible. This way people can help you faster and you're saving everyone who's interested in helping you from retyping those parts of a document.

Comment: Also, please note that the correct way to use `siunitx` to typeset values with a unit is by using `\SI{3.9}{\ohm}` instead of `3.8\si{\ohm}` or `$3.7$\si{\ohm}`. This way proper spacing and flexible number formatting is ensured (or, if in `circuitikz` by using it's syntax as shown in [@Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/563144/117050)).

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

You are almost done ...  I only correct syntax for resistors' values using option `siunitx` at loading `circuitikz` package, push parallel resistors' values on opposite sides and add missing line for closing circuit loop:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[V=5<V>]    (0,4) % The voltage source
            to[R=3.9<\ohm>] (4,4)
            to[R=19<\ohm>]  (4,0) % The resistor
            to[short]       (3,0)
            to[short]       (3,.5)
            to [R,a=33<\ohm>] (1,.5)  |-  (0,0) % <---
      (3,0) to[short]       (3,-.5)
            to [R=69<\ohm>] (1,-.5)             % <----
            to [short]      (1,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This answer shows how `siunitx` should be used to typeset numbers with units (if the `siunitx` option of `circuitikz` isn't used, or outside of `cicruitikz`, as the `circuitikz` syntax is already shown by [@Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/563144/117050)) as well as the usage of `coordinate`s to ease the process of positioning things (plus relative positioning by using the `++` syntax).

The label of bipoles can be switched to the other side by using `l_=<label>` instead, so for a resistor use `R, l_=<label>` instead of `R=<label>`. I also flipped the voltage direction by using `v<=<label>` instead of `v=<label>`, and placed junctions by using `-*`.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0,0) coordinate (start)
    to[V,v<=\SI{5}{\volt}] ++(0,4) % The voltage source
    to[R=\SI{3.9}{\ohm}] ++(4,0) coordinate (topright)
    to[R=\SI{19}{\ohm}] (start-|topright) % The resistor
    to[short,-*] ++(-1,0) coordinate (pright)
    to[short] ++(0,.5)
    to[R,l_=\SI{33}{\ohm}] ++(-2,0) coordinate (tmp)
    to[short,-*] (start-|tmp) coordinate (pleft)
    (pright)
    to[short] ++(0,-.5) coordinate (tmp)
    to[R=\SI{69}{\ohm}] (tmp-|pleft)
    to[short] (pleft)
    to[short, -.] (start) % the `-.` ensures there is no gap here
    ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]